# Debian9 installation from 1400 to 150 packages without desktop

Tags: debian-installer

For my personal laptop I will install Debian9 with lightDM/Awesome.
During the installation process (with tasksel) I have just checked standard system utility.

Just for my comprehension, if the packages installed pass from 1400 to 150, it is just for the Desktop Environment ?

I know i will install all tools manually (unzip, session locker, ...).
But I want to make sure that there are no essential tools missing for the system and that it will work well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, roughly 150 packages matches up with the standard minimal base installation, and 1400 is about what I would expect from most distributions that provide a full desktop environment and don't give the user options to exclude optional dependencies during the install.  The standard set of desktop items has a pretty large number of dependencies, especially stuff like web browsers or office software, but a minimalistic system only really needs a few dozen packages and their dependencies.

As a point of reference, the Debian Sid testing VM I run has 427 packages installed currently.  About half of those are dependencies pulled in by installing the `build-essential`, `gdb`, and `vim` packages, and about a fifth of the rest are from manual installation of a small number of things I have on every system I use (`htop`, `lsof`, `strace`, etc) that have pretty minimal dependencies.  When I initially installed the system, it had about 200 some packages, but I also selected both the base system and the SSH server options during the install.